# Please provide latest version FFmpeg library(.so) file for android

Tags: ffmpeg

i have using the following library files:

```
{"ffmpeg",
        "libavcodec.so", "libavcodec.so.52", "libavcodec.so.52.99.1",
        "libavcore.so", "libavcore.so.0", "libavcore.so.0.16.0",
        "libavdevice.so", "libavdevice.so.52", "libavdevice.so.52.2.2",
        "libavfilter.so", "libavfilter.so.1", "libavfilter.so.1.69.0",
        "libavformat.so", "libavformat.so.52", "libavformat.so.52.88.0",
        "libavutil.so", "libavutil.so.50", "libavutil.so.50.34.0",
        "libswscale.so", "libswscale.so.0", "libswscale.so.0.12.0"
};
```

when i used the following commands

```
String[] ffmpegCommand ={"/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg","-i",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/bg.png",
                    "-r","5","-i",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/image%d.png","-filter_complex","overlay","-shortest",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/video.mp4"};
```

i got Error Like

```
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***FFmpeg version UNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  built on Jul 28 2011 16:47:07 with gcc 4.4.3***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --sysroot=/Developer/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-3/arch-arm --soname-prefix=/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ --enable-shared --disable-symver --enable-small --optimization-flags=-O2 --enable-encoder=mpeg2video --enable-encoder=nellymoser --enable-protocol=file --prefix=../build/ffmpeg/armeabi --extra-cflags= --extra-ldflags=***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavutil     50.34. 0 / 50.34. 0***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavcore      0.16. 0 /  0.16. 0***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavcodec    52.99. 1 / 52.99. 1***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavformat   52.88. 0 / 52.88. 0***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavdevice   52. 2. 2 / 52. 2. 2***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libavfilter    1.69. 0 /  1.69. 0***
10-15 11:22:55.970: E/MJPEG_FFMPEG(2620): ***  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0***
```

Please can anyone provide latest FFmpeg library file?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: @PrvN really sorry i didn't find out latest FFmpeg library (.so) file but you can create yourself FFmpeg library using FFmpeg C/C++ coding.